# const char* pointer arithmetic warning

Tags: c, pointers

With my compiler (Apple llvm-gg-4.2) this code:

```
void fun1(const char *s)
{
    char* t = s+1;
}
void fun2(char *s)
{
    char* t = s+1;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* a;
    fun1(a);
    fun2(a);
}
```

gives this warning:

junk.c:3: warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

on fun1 but not on fun2.  Why?

Comment: Because you're losing the const bit in func1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fun1 is taking const char* and is being assigned to char*
Whereas fun2 is taking a char* and being assigned to char* which is fine.

`If you are assigning a constant pointer to a non-const pointer, this means you can modify the const pointer by using the const pointer`

In this case, inside fun1 if you do `t[0] = 'a'` its not legal because you are modifying const memory, which is why compiler warns you

Comment: Thx, Mayank and the others.  It makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 3):

In `fun1`, `s` is a `const char *`. When you do `char* t = s+1;`, you "remove" that `const`status from `s`. Hence the "discards qualifiers". If this were C++, you would get a compiler error instead of a warning.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why is in `fun1` you are converting `const char *` to a `char *`.  This is losing the `const` qualifier and opening the door to modify data the function likely didn't intend to be modified.

To fix this change the `fun1` body to

```
const char* t = s+1;
```